# Navigation Tool Tip Wrong Place

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation, tooltip

I created tooltip arrows for this navigation. They show up on hover but they also show up in the bottom of the drop down. I am wondering what code is keeping them there!

Here is the code i am using to implement them.

[Link to dev site](http://mycustomdevelopment.com/campfire/)

```
.cftopnavrightlower ul > li:hover:after {
content: '';
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid #FFC700;
margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: try `.cftopnavrightlower > ul li:hover:after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need greater specificity for the UL you are targeting for the arrows.  ul.flyout is being styled with an arrow given your current selector.

This may work better:

```
#menu-header-nav > li:hover:after {
content: '';
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid #FFC700;
margin-left: -10px;
}
```